# Vector push_back in while and for loops returns SIGABRT signal (signal 6) (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, sigabrt

I'm making a C++ game which requires me to initialize 36 numbers into a vector. You can't initialize a vector with an initializer list, so I've created a while loop to initialize it faster. I want to make it push back 4 of each number from 2 to 10, so I'm using an int named fourth to check if the number of the loop is a  multiple of 4. If it is, it changes the number pushed back to the next number up. When I run it, though, I get SIGABRT. It must be a problem with fourth, though, because when I took it out, it didn't give the signal. 
Here's the program:

```
for (int i; i < 36;) {
    int fourth = 0;
    fourth++;
    fourth%=4;
    vec.push_back(i);
    if (fourth == 0) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not initialize `i`. Use `for (int i = 0; i<36;)`. Also, a new variable `forth` is allocated on each iteration of the loop body. Thus the test `fourth==0` will always yield `false`.

> I want to make it push back 4 of each number from 2 to 10

I would use the most straight forward approach:

```
for (int value = 2; value <= 10; ++value)
{
  for (int count = 0; count < 4; ++count)
  {
    vec.push_back(value);
  }
}
```

The only optimization I would do is making sure that the capacity of the vector is sufficient before entering the loop. I would leave other optimizations to the compiler. My guess is, what you gain by omitting the inner loop, you lose by frequent modulo division.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. Guess mah brainz wasn't workin yesterdays.

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize i, and you are resetting fourth in every iteration. Also, with your for loop condition, I do not think it will do what you want.

I think this should work:

```
int fourth = 0;
for (int i = 2; i<=10;) {
  fourth++;
  fourth%=4;
  vec.push_back(i);
  if (fourth==0) {
     i++;
  }      
}
```

Comment: I couldn't see this, either? I think I needed some sleep :/

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to create a static array declaration and pass that array into the vector at initialization without issue.  Pretty clean too:

```
const int initialValues[36] = {0,1,2...,35};
std::vector foo(initialValues);
```

Works with constants, but haven't tried it with non const arrays.